# Difference in io.on and socket.on in socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets

Is this diagram gives correct representation of io and socket in node js server?
What I want to say is ....
First we write- const io=require("socket.io")(8080);

then we write- io.on('connection',(socket)=>{//some logic...})
Is this establishes some kind of socket.io server running inside node js server at port 8080?
after this inside io.on we write- socket.on(event,action);
Is this socket.on like opening in socket server where users get connected???
If the diagram is a mistake plz correct me..
THANK YOU ...
[Diagram Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTv9T.png)

Answer (score 0):

`io.on` listens for ***all*** events, which allows you to do this:

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(8080);

let users = 0;
io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
  users++;
  console.log(users);
});
io.on('disconnect',(socket)=>{
  console.log('A user disconnected!');
});
```

On the other hand, `socket.on` only listens for data on *it's own* server, so it will ignore other servers' data.